# Visual Differences between vim on virtualbox Ubuntu guest (through putty) OR gVim on Windows host

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gvim, microsoft-windows, colorscheme, font

Ok, it's a curiosity more than a real question, I apologize in advance for long post:

Usually I code with vim on a ubuntu headless, as a virtualbox guest on my stupid windows 7 host; I access linux terminal using amazing putty (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

BTW, I love putty full-screen mode (Alt-Enter) and here a screenshot of a editing:

[image: vim screeenshot using putty]

Yesterday I tryied to port my ubuntu vim environment using http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc native gVim on windows...:
I copied "as is" my .vimrc and plugins directories from the ubuntu to windows, to have my beloved configurations, plugins, colorscheme (BTW, I use "Monokay-Refined" colorscheme).

BTW, the environment is perfectly replicated, a part the Session.vim (that seem incompatible).

gVim configuration:
After some moments of panic with gVim configuration... by example I spent some time to understand how to make configurations persistent (changing and fixing the awful default font, remove menubar/toolbar, etc.) achieving a full-screen experience similar to that I use with putty....

BTW, I found excellent beautiful utility to do that: https://github.com/derekmcloughlin/gvimfullscreen_win32/tree/master)

OK, with gVim on windows I finally got the "same" full-screen feeling I usually have using vim on ubuntu through putty, see:
[image: gVim screenshot on windows]

BUT, to be meticulous, as you can see here below... screenshots are similar but not exactly the SAME!?

I mean, I realized that COLORS are a bit differents accessingsame ruby file (by example) on the ubuntu through putty, and a copy of the same file on windows, acccessed with gVim ?!  despite the colorscheme, font and all other configs are identical! It seems to me that colors on the gVim installation are a bit "better"... and last but not least some character attributes (italic, bold, etc.) are bettere visualized on gVim that on putty ssh access...

It's a question of putty color/font "rendering" ?

BTW, visualized code is from my ruby project: https://github.com/solyaris/pere

thanks
giorgio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PuTTY, like other high-color terminals, only supports a fixed color palette of 256 colors. GVIM can use the full 24-bit RGB color space; that's why you see "finer" nuances there.

As for attributes, GVIM offers *undercurl*, which is not present in any terminal, and free mixture of bold (depending on configuration shown with lighter color instead) and italic (not offered in PuTTY).

Comment: Note that many terminals allow configuration of the colours they use, so you can use the same shade of red/blue/etc. as gVim uses. You're still limited to 256 colours in total though, and the changes apply to all programs. *Some* terminals also have the concept of "profiles", so you may be able to create a "Vim profile" for those terminals.